# Datepicker not showing - Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So this is the markup of the datepicker:

```
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-offset-9">
          <label class="control-label">Pick Date</label>
          <div class="input-group date" id="dp3" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" readonly="" value="12-02-2012">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Actually, it looks like this:

[image]

However, when I click the calendar icon there's no table-look-a-like date picker showing. 
I've included the following css and js:

```
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript"src="js/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

I also have called the function at `<head></head>` and at the end of the `<body></body>` just to make sure. But, still no response when I click the button.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#dp3").datepicker({ autoclose: true, todayHighlight: true });
});

      $(window).on('load',function(){
       $("#dp3").datepicker({ autoclose: true, todayHighlight: true });
});

    </script>
```

I have changed some of the CSS JS code because of the Bootstrap 3 updated code, source: http://kenyontechnology.com/2013/10/08/datepicker-for-bootstrap-with-twitter-bootstrap-3-0/

So, I want to have a table-look-a-like datepicker when I click the calendar button. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: I just implemented the fix from kenyontechnology.com myself, and it works fine. Are all your included files being found? Are there any console errors?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that you're calling `$('#dp3').datepicker()` twice.

Comment: @Blazemonger I've tried and finally I found the problem. The problem is I've included jquery.js which may be interfere with the jquery-2.0.3.js. After I removed jquery.js, voila it works. Thanks for the help bro

Comment: @Blazemonger according to your implementation, is the input text changed when you pick any dates on the datepicker?

Comment: Would be a good idea to now answer this question with the answer, or alternatively remove the question since it's now been resolved.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue - in my case in the jQuery wiring $('#someid').datepicker() 'someid' was the id of the 'input' and where it should have been of the container div. which means - it worked when you click the input box but not the glyphicon button.

I have a working copy fiddle is here :
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lro8kxjx/6/embedded/result/)

The jsfiddle code is here : (Note: the reference to jQuery 2.0.2 and also the external reosurces tab in jsFiddle editor)

```
   http://jsfiddle.net/Lro8kxjx/6/

<div class="col-xs-6 ">
<div class="form-group ">
    <div class='input-group date' id='datepicker'>
        <input type="text" id="processdate" class="form-control" placeholder="Processing Date..." name="processdate" /> <span class="input-group-addon btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    startDate: '-180d',
    endDate: '+1d',
    autoclose: true
});  });
```